# Find the lowest number using Map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

We have sensors data coming from different sensors . The sensors data will be like

```
Tag id , listener_id,rssi_value,time 
5 , 50 , -35 , 1495568512( epoch time)
5, 50 , -80, 1495569916
5,50, --33 ,1495568512
5 ,50,-32 ,1495568512
6,50,-10,1495568512
6,60,-99,1495568512
6,60,-33,1495568512
```

Above are the sample data , we would like to find the minimum rssi value using map reduce .

Logic needs to check is like

With the particular tag id and appropriate listener id what is the minimum rssi value should be the output for the particular timestamp ( timestamp may be differ) and the respective value should print

Output be like

```
5 ,50,-32 ,1495568512
5, 50 , -80, 1495569916
6,50,-10,1495568512
6,60,-33,1495568512
```

Is this possible . Can anyone help me in logic with programming.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to build up a Map with `Tag_id+'_'+Listiner_id+'_'+timestamp` as the key and the lowest rssi_value as the value. So just iterate over the rows, adding each if this is a new key or lower value.